# Android resource not found exception for dynamic feature

Tags: android, android-resources, dynamic-feature-module

Hi I have created one Android application and created one dynamic feature in it. In this dynamic feature in one of the fragments, I am trying to set a custom font for text view.

```
ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.custom_montserrat_bold)
```

Here `custom_montserrat_bold` is present inside the dynamic feature. Inside my activity which hosts this feature fragment I have added the following code

```
 override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base)
    SplitCompat.installActivity(this)
}
```

Following is the Android manifest for dynamic feature

```
<dist:module
    dist:instant="false"
    dist:title="customModule">
    <dist:delivery>
        <dist:install-time />
    </dist:delivery>
    <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
</dist:module>
```

I am getting the following error

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Font resource ID #0x7e070001 could not be retrieved.
```

It is not happening for all devices.

Comment: I'm trying to implement dynamic feature. I have fragments in my on demand module. It downloads and installs successfully. But then it crashes saying resources not found and points to the line where i inflate the layout. 
Have you got answer or know the answer to my query? Please do share

Comment: @nilkash  Have you found any solution for this ? I m also facing similar problem. Please update if you have got any solution for this.